# How to check the option value in drop down with previous value?

Tags: jquery

If the option value and previous matches it won't display in that drop down using jquery

Edit

Populating the selectbox based on user's comment

```
$.each(g_Vehicle, function (index) { 
     var iYear = g_Vehicle[index].Year;
     sMake = g_Vehicle[index].Make;
            selectYear = '<option value="' + iYear + '">' + iYear + '</option>'; selectMake =   '<option value="' + sMake + '">' + sMake + '</option>'; 
     $("#DropDown_Year").append(selectYear);    
     $("#DropDown_Make").append(selectMake); 
});
```

Comment: can any one help me to do this

Comment: You mean the option immediately preceding to the selected option ?

Comment: put a proper question together that explains what it is exactly you are needing... in words that aren't open to ambiguous interpretation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('body').delegate('#DropDown_Year','change',function(){
var prev = $(this).find('option:selected').prev().val();

  if($(this).val() ==  prev ){ 
    alert('Matched');
     //your curent value and previous value are the same
  }else{
    //not same
  }


 });
});
```

Comment: In my code i used json object to get all the values into drop down without using html. Its was working but i have to check the values in the drop down.If the values is already existed i wont display in the drop down that is problem

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us how you make the dropdown ?

Comment: $.each(g_Vehicle, function (index) {
            var iYear = g_Vehicle[index].Year;
                sMake = g_Vehicle[index].Make;
                selectYear = '<option value="' + iYear + '">' + iYear + '</option>';
                selectMake = '<option value="' + sMake + '">' + sMake + '</option>';
                $("#DropDown_Year").append(selectYear);
                $("#DropDown_Make").append(selectMake);

        });

Answer (score 1):

You can store the previous is global variable and access it on change. It is supposed that in start element at zero index is selected.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J9Tj4/)**

```
previousVal = $('#selectId option').eq(0).val();    

$('#selectId').change(function(){
    alert(previousVal);
    previous = $('#selectId').val();
});​
```

*To store previous item text you can use text() method instead of val()*

Comment: With out using alert how can i write this?

Comment: Where you want to write ? you can use console.log(previousVal)